# how to make content inside div to autorefresh every 1 second?

Tags: php, html

is it possible to automaticaly refresh the content inside profile-stats every 1 second ?

```
<div class="profile-stats" >

            <ul>
            
                <!-- this is user posts count -->
                <li><span class="profile-stat-count"id="user_post_count"><?php echo $wo['user_profile']['details']['post_count'];?></span>&nbsp;<?php echo $wo['lang']['posts'];?></li>
                                  <!-- this is Privacy setting to show followers or following -->

            
                <!-- this is user followers count -->
                <li><span class="profile-stat-count"><?php echo $wo['user_profile']['details']['followers_count'];?></span><a href="<?php echo Wo_SeoLink('index.php?link1=timeline&u=' . $wo['user_profile']['username'] . '&type=followers');?>" data-ajax="?link1=timeline&u=<?php echo $wo['user_profile']['username']?>&type=followers">&nbsp;<?php echo $wo['lang']['followers'];?></a></li>
                
                    <!-- this is user following count -->
                <li><span class="profile-stat-count"><?php echo $wo['user_profile']['details']['following_count'];?></span><a href="<?php echo Wo_SeoLink('index.php?link1=timeline&u=' . $wo['user_profile']['username'] . '&type=following');?>" data-ajax="?link1=timeline&u=<?php echo $wo['user_profile']['username']?>&type=following">&nbsp;<?php echo $wo['lang']['following'];?></a></li>
        
            </ul>

        </div>
```

Comment: If you want updates with such near-real-time frequency then investigate server-sent events, or websockets.

Answer (score 0):

Using `jQuery load()` and an interval timer is about the simplest.

```
setInterval(function(){
   $('#my_div').load('/path/to/server/source');
}, 2000) /* time in milliseconds (ie 2 seconds)*/
```

`load()` is a shorthand method for `$.ajax`

This assumes that you would set up a server side script that only outputs the content for that element. You could also use a selector fragment within `load` url to parse a full page for the specific content

Comment: Technically this could work but realistically, using AJAX polling with such frequency is likely to blow up the server, unless it's fairly big and the number of concurrent users of the page stays fairly low.

Comment: you can use react.js for this type of issue.

Comment: is it possible to make <?php echo $wo['user_profile']['details']['post_count'];?> reload all the time to keep fetching new data ?

Comment: if you are using the php code segment then you need to use ajax or you should build your application by react.js/vue.js or such type to reactive framework.

Answer (score 0):

It works for me.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('#post_button').click(function(){
  var post_name = $('#post_name').val();
  //trim() is used to remover spaces
  if($.trim(post_name) != '')
  {
   $.ajax({
    url:"post.php",
    method:"POST",
    data:{post_name:post_name},
    dataType:"text",
    success:function(data)
    {
     $('#post_name').val("");
    }
   });
  }
 });
 
 setInterval(function(){//setInterval() method execute on every interval until called clearInterval()
  $('#load_posts').load("display.php").fadeIn("slow");
  //load() method fetch data from fetch.php page
 }, 1000);
 
});
</script>
```